# Parsing lines of text in a txt file with a batch script?

Tags: file, parsing, batch-file

so I'm currently working on a batch file which scans the network. what I have done is created a text file which has just the IP of every computer on the network that responded to a ping request, and the output of the ping request is saved to a file called IPAdresses.txt
::==========================================================================

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
```

::File reset and variables

```
echo. > %~dp0Logs\IPAddresses2.txt
SET fl=%~dp0Logs\IPAddresses.txt
```

::This command does the ping request and saves just the replies to %~dp0Logs\IPAddresses.txt. 
::Every returned ping will make a line in the file that looks like this "Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64".

```
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,254) DO ping -n 1 192.168.1.%%i | FIND /i “Reply” >> %fl%
```

::This command Parse the "Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64" line in the file and saves the output to %~dp0Logs\IPAddresses2.txt.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%t in (`findstr /b /c:Reply from %fl% `) do (
echo %%t >> %~dp0Logs\IPAddresses2.txt
)
```

::-----------THE ISSUE-----------

::The issue is the parsing. The last command will only parse "192.168.1.1: " this is because it only takes the 3 Token (or the third set of characters in the string) in the line. I need to get rid of the ": " from "192.168.1.1: ". To be clear i want to remove the semicolon and the following space, at the end of the IP address.

::i have tried to put every line into a variable and cut the tailing characters but i cannot get it to work.
::Or is there a way to alter the FOR command to do this??

I have been searching for two days now and trying all sorts of work arounds, but no luck.
I need just the IP's in a text files for further functions, and network wide NET commands.

Any help would be appreciated 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Never too late to answer, eh? This gets you most of the way there. There are probably cleaner ways of doing this, but I tried to follow your code as much as I could.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
SET fl=%~dp0Logs\IPAddresses.txt
set net=10.2.10.
set start=71
set end=75

  FOR /L %%i IN (%start%,1,%end%) DO ping -n 1 %net%%%i | findstr /i Reply >> %fl%
  for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%t in (`findstr /b /c:Reply from %fl% `) do (
  set ip=%%t
  set ip=!ip:~0,-1!
echo !ip!
)
```